# PHP Fatal error: Class 'vfsStream' not found in Bootstrap.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpunit

I just pull Codeigniter from https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter. And I have installed phpunit and pear. When I do `phpunit tests/` it showed:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'vfsStream' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/tests/Bootstrap.php on line 32
>
> Fatal error: Class 'vfsStream' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/tests/Bootstrap.php on line 32

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install before testing

```
wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```